# Unable to load application Heroku

Tags: node.js, github, heroku

I forked a project and connected my GitHub account with Heroku to import and deploy the project.

I'm getting an error while launching the app.

Project link:https://github.com/ixartz/Astro-boilerplate

Heroku Log: https://textdoc.co/2Qg3zWcb9BDwOIUC

Comment: More logs here: https://justpaste.it/2n7ci

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.